# Delphi COM server processes one request at a time

Tags: multithreading, delphi, com

I have an out-of-process COM server originally developed in Delphi 7, then D2006, recently recompiled under XE3.  Under the XE3 version, requests are processed one at a time. If one is in progress when another comes in, ObjectCount goes up, but the second isn't processed until the first finishes.  The D7/D2006 versions processed the requests concurrently.

The server maintains a database.  Most requests are processed very quickly, but a few take a minute or more.  There is an form with a Memo that displays an activity log, that's the whole UI.  Not sure what other information would be helpful here.

Any ideas why the XE3 version would behave differently?  Or, in general, why the second server object might wait for the first to finish?

Here's an example.  I installed XE5, created a VCL app, and added a COM object with one method, and created a test client.  It processed one request at a time.  I compiled the same project in D2006 (just had to remove the unit prefixes) and it processed them concurrently.

What am I doing wrong?

```
unit Unit2;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, ComObj, Project1_TLB, StdVcl;

type
  TTest = class(TTypedComObject, ITest)
  protected
    function Method1(N: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ;

function TTest.Method1(N: Integer): HResult;
var I: Integer;
begin
for I := 1 to N do
  Sleep( 1000);
end;

initialization
  TTypedComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TTest, Class_Test,
    ciMultiInstance, tmFree);
end.
```

Comment: Any chance of an SSCCE?

Comment: I edited the post to clarify what I'm looking for.  I don't have a short example that demonstrates the problem, but maybe I can come up with one. Thanks.

Comment: SSCCE Explained: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: @user2933755, the excercise will be worth it.  By simplifying the problem, you may find the solution yourself. For example, the database may have nothing to do with it. or it may have everything to do with it. Right now, you don't know.  I'd shoot for having your server simply increment a counter, sleep for 10 seconds, and then return the result.  This will demonstrate whether the server is blocking or not.

Comment: Also see http://sscce.org as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced through the simple Delphi XE5 server above.  Application.Initialize -> ComServ.InitComServer -> ComObj.InitComObj -> CoInitializeEx( nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED), which returns RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE.  The server processes one request at a time.

On tracing through the same project compiled under D2006, the CoInitializeEx call returns S_OK, and the server processes requests concurrently.

I added a call to CoUninitialize in the project source before the call to Application.Initialize. With that, the XE5 version processes requests concurrently.  This worked for the production server that prompted the question, too.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the threading model of each version of the COM object. It sounds like the XE3 version is Apartment-threaded (where COM serializes requests) while the earlier version is Multi/Free-threaded instead (where COM does not serialize requests).

Comment: After I realized the XE3 version had a problem, I went back to the source code for the D2006 version, did a fresh compile in D2006, and confirmed that requests were processed concurrently.  Then I closed D2006, started XE3, opened the same project, compiled in XE3, and tested.  The second request waited.  So it was the same threading model (and everything else) in both cases.

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY sure? Did you verify the COM object registration in the Registry (not in the code) is the same for both versions?  Also keep in mind that XE+ uses a different COM framework (DAX) than earlier Delphi versions used, so that may be a factor as well.

Comment: >  Also keep in mind that XE+ uses a different COM framework (DAX) // is there any more details on that ?

Comment: @DavidSmith if the sources are same that does not mean the actualy values are the same. There maybe  default values in variables, that you do not override in neither PAS source nor DFM source,  but which are different in 2006 and XE3

Comment: When I searched for details on how to check the registry, I read that threading for out of process servers isn't stored there.  Is that wrong?

Comment: Out-of-process COM servers have threading models stored in the Registry, just like any other COM object.  In-process or out-of-process doesn't change the fact that the caller still needs to know the threading model in order to access the COM object directly or via a proxy.

Comment: I can't get even a simple test server (...ciMultiInstance, tmFree), newly created in XE3 or XE5, to process requests concurrently.